# Como Mapear un archivo de texto en C#?

Tags: c#, archivo, consola

tengo un txt con lo siguiente

```
1|Gerente|1000
2|Cajero|500
3|Limpieza|450
4|Paquetes|450
```

Y lo separo con

```
char[] delimiterChars = { '\n', '|' };
string siguienteLinea;
string textPuesto = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Puesto.txt");
string[] lineasPuesto = textPuesto.Split(delimiterChars);
int i;

for (i=0;i<lineasPuesto.Length;i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(lineasPuesto[i]);
}
```

Entonces eso separa cada palabra en una cadena diferente pero necesito agrupar el código que es el primer dígito de cada fila con el nombre del puesto que es el segundo dato y el sueldo el cual es el tercero, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo? Para por ejemplo saber cuál es el código siguiente si quiero ingresar un puesto nuevo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no entiendo tu problema.. nosabes como unir las partes de tu array?

Comment: puedes mostrar que resultado esperas tener? sería más fácil de entender mi estimado :D

Comment: Declara una clase Emplead{int id, string Puesto, decimal Sueldo} el texto lo vas a leer linea por linea, cada linea es un nuevo empleado e igualas el valor de sus propiedades

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto una solucion a medida de tu problema.
Utilizo parte de tu solucion y le agrego banderas para ir entrando en los if y separando las cadenas y rellenando el objeto.
Lo mas optimo seria que tu archivo de texto ya estuviera en forma json o xml para poder parsearlo directamente y no tener que hacer este tipo de trabajos.

```
        char[] delimiterChars = { '\n', '|' };
        string path = Application.StartupPath + "\\texto.txt";
        Stream stream = File.OpenRead(path);

        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);

        List<Trabajador> listatrabajor = new List<Trabajador>();

        string[] lineasPuesto;
        List<string> lista = new List<string>();

        int b = 0;

        lineasPuesto = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split(delimiterChars);
        lista = lineasPuesto.ToList();

        int id = 0, sueldo = 0;
        string posicion = "";

        foreach (var item in lista)
        {
            if (b == 0)
                id = Convert.ToInt32(item);
            if (b == 1)
                posicion = item;
            if (b == 2)
            {
                sueldo = Convert.ToInt32(item);
                listatrabajor.Add(new Trabajador { idPuesto = id, Puesto = posicion, Sueldo = sueldo });
                b = 2;
            }

            b++;
            if (b == 3)
                b = 0;
        }


}
```

Debes crear una clase, para armar tu List

```
public class Trabajador
{
    public int idPuesto { get; set; }
    public string Puesto { get; set; }
    public int Sueldo { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero de todo crea una clase para contener a tus trabajadores como pudiera ser:

```
public class Worker
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Job { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}
```

Si el salario puede tener decimales utiliza `float`o el tipo de dato que necesites.

Después donde vayas a leer el fichero puedes hacer algo así:

```
var file = new StreamReader("Puesto.txt");
var line = string.Empty;
var result = new List<Worker>();
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
        string[] items = line.Split('|');
        result.Add(new Worker
        { 
            Id = Convert.ToInt32(items[0]),
            Job = items[1],
            Salary = Convert.ToInt32(items[2])
        });
}
```

Ese código asume que el contenido del fichero SIEMPRE va a ser como el que has puesto. Si hubieran más o menos columnas, tendrías que adaptar el mapeo manual dentro del bucle. En tu lista `result` tendrías todos los trabajadores del fichero de texto y podrías acceder a ellos por cualquiera de sus propiedades, como por ejemplo, si quieres buscar al trabajador que tenga el identificador 3:

```
var worker = result.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Id == 3);
```

De la misma forma puedes añadir elementos a la lista sin problemas, hacer que se ordenen por el identificador, o cualquier otra función propia de esta estructura de datos.